# Getting and comparing area of ArcPy geometry from extent object

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I'm trying to get a numerical value for the area of a polygon that I am generating from an extent object.  In this case, I am using the "onRectangle" function in the Python Addins for ArcPy.  The problem starts when using the getArea method on the polygon geometry.  I have no intention of writing this polygon to disk.  Ultimately, I want to be able to compare the extent of a user drawn rectangle to the dataframe extent. Here's what I've got so far.

```
def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    frameExtent = rectangle_geometry
    XMAX = frameExtent.XMax
    XMIN = frameExtent.XMin
    YMAX = frameExtent.YMax
    YMIN = frameExtent.YMin
    pnt1 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMIN)
    pnt2 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMAX)
    pnt3 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMAX)
    pnt4 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMIN)
    print XMAX, XMIN, YMAX, YMIN
    array = arcpy.Array()
    array.add(pnt1)
    array.add(pnt2)
    array.add(pnt3)
    array.add(pnt4)
    array.add(pnt1)
    rectPoly = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    global rectArea
    rectArea = rectPoly.getArea()
    print str(rectArea)
    return rectArea
```

The python window in ArcMap returns this error:

> TypeError: Invalid geometry type for method.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 Advanced license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of a rectangle is just height * width, so you can cut to the chase with

```
def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    frameExtent = rectangle_geometry
    xmax = frameExtent.XMax
    xmin = frameExtent.XMin
    ymax = frameExtent.YMax
    ymin = frameExtent.YMin
    return (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)
```

*Note: This assumes Cartesian map units -- If using a geographic coordinate system, then you need to construct the geometry and use* `Polygon.getArea('GEODESIC','SQUAREMETERS')` *or* `SQUAREKILOMETERS`, *as appropriate.*

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the help on [Polygon (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000061000000) the method getArea() takes a string parameter for `type` i.e. it "Returns the area of the feature using a measurement type."

> PLANAR measurements reflect the projection of geographic data onto the
> 2D surface (in other words, they will not take into account the
> curvature of the earth). GEODESIC, GREAT_ELLIPTIC, LOXODROME, and
> PRESERVE_SHAPE  measurement types may be chosen as an alternative, if
> desired.

Comment: I used those but they always failed to yeild the area as I expected.  However, I realized I was simply over complicating the matter and took Vince's advice and just did the math in code instead.  I'm not sure how to use his response as the answer.